# VBA How to autofit row height with merged cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic data not set in  data height  . how to dynamism height set in data height.

```
sub test()
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 16).Value = "Process inform HMI finish oil fiber display not show we check found HMI damage after we check no have spare after we move HMI alarm display at control spinning to install. But the type of HMI not same. To convert graphic display.After transfer to HMI and test operation finished. Test system with process is working normal. Process inform HMI finish oil fiber display not show we check found HMI damage after we check no have spare after we move HMI alarm display at control spinning to install. But the type of HMI not same. To convert graphic display.After transfer to HMI and test operation finished. Test system with process is working normal. Process inform HMI finish oil fiber display not show we check found HMI damage after we check no have spare after we move HMI alarm display at control spinning to install. But the type of HMI not same. To convert graphic display.After transfer to HMI and test operation finished. Test system with process is working normal. Process inform HMI finish oil fiber display not show we check found HMI damage after we check no have spare after we move HMI alarm display at control spinning to install. But the type of HMI not same. To convert graphic display.After transfer to HMI and test operation finished. Test system with process is working normal."
End sub
```

cell data full data display now how can I am using "WrapText" and "AutoFit" but full data display  cell but  more then word in hide in cell . row height 409 how to increasing cell height .

give me the sample link and out put.

Comment: I don't understand. Your code autofits the column(s) not the row.

Comment: Hi dynamic  row height set in deepen on the every cell data number of line to increasing row height.

Comment: i am using marge cell how to set in row height dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use merge-cell and Auto-fit, only use wrap-text and set the column width to any desired number which looks good on your data.

```
Sub test()

    Dim row_num
    Dim col_num

    row_num = 2
    col_num = 16

    Columns(col_num).ColumnWidth = 65

    Sheets(1).Cells(row_num, col_num).Value = "Process inform HMI finish oil fiber display not show we check found HMI damage after we check no have spare after we move HMI alarm display at control spinning to install. But the type of HMI not same. To convert graphic display.After transfer to HMI and test operation finished. Test system with process is working  normal. Process inform HMI finish oil fiber display not show we check found HMI damage after we check no have spare after we move HMI alarm display at control spinning to install. But the type of HMI not same. To convert graphic display.After transfer to HMI and test operation finished. Test system with process is working normal.Process inform HMI finish oil fiber display not show we check found HMI damage after we check no have spare after we move HMI alarm display at control spinning to install. But the type of HMI not same.To convert graphic display.After transfer to HMI and test operation finished." _
    & "Test system with process is working normal. Process inform HMI finish oil fiber display not show we check found HMI damage after we check no have spare after we move HMI alarm display at control spinning to install. But the type of HMI not same. To convert graphic display.After transfer to HMI and test operation finished. Test system with process is working normal."

    Sheets(1).Cells(row_num, col_num).WrapText = True

End Sub
```

**Edited Version**

You can check the below code for the auto fitting merged cells.

The cell width for column A to C is set to 12 each and for the height the ration that is 45%  of text length depends upon this width, if you want to change the width, you have to change the ratio as well.

```
Sub test1()


    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = " Testing Testing TestingTestingTesting Testing Testing TestingTestingTesting Testing TestingTesting Testing Testing TestingTesting Testing Testing Testing TestingTesting Testing TestingTesting Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing TestingTestingTesting Testing"
    Range("A2:C2").Merge
    Range("A2:C2").WrapText = True

    Columns("A:C").ColumnWidth = 12

    text_length = Len(Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value)
    Rows("2:2").RowHeight = text_length * 0.45


End Sub
```

Comment: Columns(col_num).ColumnWidth = 500   
Error
      ---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications
---------------------------
Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: try to decrease it to about 180

Comment: maximum width of column can only be less than 255, and 180 is about width of normal screen, you may not want to have a column wider than the screen itself.

Comment: coloum height how can increasing

Comment: Sheets(1).Cells(row_num, col_num).WrapText = True. will automatically set the height for the text, but if you want to do it manually you can use somthing similar to Rows(12).RowHeight = 40

Comment: Sub test1()
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = " Testing Testing TestingTestingTesting  Testing  Testing  TestingTestingTesting  Testing  TestingTesting  Testing  Testing  TestingTesting  Testing  Testing  Testing  TestingTesting  Testing  TestingTesting  Testing  Testing  Testing  Testing  Testing  Testing  Testing  TestingTestingTesting  Testing"
    Range("A2:C2").Merge
    Range("A2:C2").WrapText = True
    Range("A2:C2").EntireRow.AutoFit
   
End Sub  "Auto fit not working"

Comment: Auto-fit does not work on merged cells, you have to write some custom function to check the ration between cell width, and string length and set the height your self